# Autonomous Differential Equations Rate of Population

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This is the question[image]

The first 2 parts are easy: 0 is stable, 3 is unstable, 6 is stable.
How do I approach part c?

Answer (score 1):

Part c)
Solve equation: $k P \left(1-\frac{P}{6}\right) \left(\frac{P}{3}-1\right)-\alpha  P=0$

Solution is $\{P\to 0\},\left\{P\to \frac{3}{2} \left(3-\frac{\sqrt{k (k-8 \alpha )}}{k}\right)\right\},\left\{P\to \frac{3 \left(\sqrt{k (k-8 \alpha )}+3 k\right)}{2 k}\right\}$

In order to get a positive real valued P solution, the condition is

$$\alpha \le \frac{k}{8}=\frac{2.24}{8}=0.28$$

Root locus plot:

[image]

Example with extinction: $P(0)=5, \alpha=0.3$

[image]

Comment: could you elaborate on your working for obtaining the solutions of P

Comment: You should be able to solve a quadratic equation
$$k \left(1-\frac{P}{6}\right) \left(\frac{P}{3}-1\right)-\alpha=0$$